# Flutter: FirebaseAuth token error: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Line App Login in Flutter, I can get user token in Line API but I'm stuck what to do next.

Right now I'm trying to use it in FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token:customToken), but it doesn't work. The error log says "PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN, The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation. [ Invalid assertion format. ], null)" are there a work around for this?

```
lineSignIn() async {
    _flutterLineLogin.startLogin(_onLoginSuccess, _onLoginError);
  }

  void _onLoginSuccess(dynamic value) {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token:value['accessToken'].toString()).then((onValue) {
      if (onValue != null) {
 ///this should be success
      }
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError.toString());
    });
  }

  void _onLoginError(Object error) {
    debugPrint("PlatformException: ${error}");
  }
```

All I need is to authenticate the token in firebase. thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Same around here. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use **`FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential`** instead of `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken`

I were also using the same source and trying to get the `AuthResult` with `Firebase` instance but failed with below `FirebaseAuth` error.

> PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN, The custom token format
>   is incorrect. Please check the documentation. [ Invalid assertion
>   format. 3 dot separated segments required. ], null)

for example, See below `Facebook` login source:

```
_loginFacebookUser() async {
    try {

      // getting token using email or public profile
      _facebookLogin.logIn(["email", "public_profile"]).then((FacebookLoginResult fbResult) {

        if (fbResult != null) {

          // if facebook login result is loggedIn then
          if (fbResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {

            String facebookToken = fbResult.accessToken.token;

            print("facebookToken is: ${facebookToken}");

            AuthCredential credential =  FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: facebookToken);

            // generating firebase authResult for facebook
//            FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token: facebookToken).then((AuthResult authResult) {
//
//              AdditionalUserInfo userInfo = authResult.additionalUserInfo;
//              print("facebook userName is: ${userInfo.username}");
//              print("facebook user profile is: ${userInfo.profile}");
//
//            }).catchError((error) {
//              print("error occurred while firebase tokenizing: $error");
//            });

            FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((AuthResult authResult) {

              AdditionalUserInfo userInfo = authResult.additionalUserInfo;
              print("facebook userName is: ${userInfo.username}");
              print("facebook user profile is: ${userInfo.profile}");

            }).catchError((error) {
              print("error occurred while firebase tokenizing: $error");
            });

          }
        } else {
          print("facebook login result is null");
        }

      }).catchError((error) {
        print("facebook login error: $error");
      });

      setState(() {});

    } catch (error) {
      print("error occurred while loggin: $error");
  }
}
```

hope it will help someone.

Comment: I don't know why someone is minus marking to this answer, which is working fine.

Comment: Should be marked as the right answer! thank you very much

Comment: People are probably looking for an example using a custom token because that's what the title suggests. However, you show signInWithCredential.

Comment: Any solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Same, for me...

As far as I'm concerned, I use a *Webview* to talk with my Firebase API (which is globally an Instagram API call with the creation of a *Firebase JWT*) and when I enter the token that I passed in a cookie to the function `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken()`... I got the same error `PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN, The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.`

I passed my JWT to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and it seems correct... But not for Firebase : [Decoded JavaScript Web Token IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so995.png).

Is this error related to Firebase or Flutter ?

If someone know where is the error...
please let me know.

Have a good day.

Comment: Any. updates on this one, i am stuck with this one?